# Guided access equivalent for macOS

Tags: macos, parental-controls, guided-access

I have written a desktop application that I would like to install onto my clients machine and then lock down so that the user cannot leave that application (Exactly the same as guided access for iOS).

Ideally, I'd like to stop the user from leaving the app at all. Otherwise I can set up parental permissions to stop the user from accessing an internet browser and messing with anything important.

**Q: Is there any Guided access equivalent for macOS?**

Comment: Heard of [Kiosk mode](http://www.dummies.com/computers/macs/mac-operating-systems/os-x-yosemite-how-to-set-the-login-for-kiosk-mode/)? Maybe give it a whirl.